# Why do we use different equations in these two questions?

Tags: combinatorics

1. Suppose you have 5 balls. How many ways can you put them in 3 boxes, when no box can stay empty?
2. Suppose you have 5 letters. How many ways can you put them in 3 boxes?

My book has different answers for these questions but to me both questions seem the same.

1: 150

2: 243

Now the math about balls was done using Stirling numbers of second kind maybe. The solution looks like it but as we are in high school we are not told about its origin. And the question about letters was solved like $3^5$.

Comment: Perhaps the balls are understood to be indistinguishable but the letters different?

Comment: Maybe if you told us the answers your book gives, it will be clearer what is meant by the questions.

Comment: Does the condition that no box remain empty apply to the letters, too?

Comment: @saulspatz that was not mentioned

Comment: Well, if the condition doesn't apply, they're clearly different questions, aren't they?  Note that $243=3^5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second, each letter can go in three boxes.  By the multiplication principle, there are $3^5=243$ ways that can happen.  For the first, you have the condition that no box is empty.  That condition means the answers must be different.  Now we subtract the cases where all the balls are in two boxes.  There are $3$ ways to choose the two boxes that are occupied, then $2^5=32$ ways to arrange the balls, so $243-3\cdot 32=147$.  We have removed the cases where all the balls are in one box twice, so we need to add them back in once.  $147+3=150$.

Comment: what if there were n balls and k boxes in the 1st question?

Comment: You would continue with the inclusion-exclusion principle